# How to use Identity Server WSO2 for authentication and authorization of a web application

Tags: authentication, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

How to use Identity Server WSO2 for authentication and authorization of a SOA based web application.

Here I am working on a web application which use

- DSS for data from DB
- For integration ESB Server (E-Mail, File Manipulation)
- And for UI HTML 5, JQuery, and JS Render.

Here my problem is User management, authentication and authorization.

My application will have a Admin UI which create User (where it should store : ldap?)

Now create user can work upon the application  : 
      User1(HR) : create employees
      user2(employees) : can load excel file (Read excel file and load it in DB with ESB Server and DSS) and an E-Mail Triggered Via ESB to (Manager) User3.

Please suggest me the architecture for this using WSO2 Since it is open source and how to use Identity server.

I have done with other part like :

- Calling DSS's Web Services from UI (HTML 5 , JQuery, JS Render) for all CRUD operation.
- Sending Mails from ESB server from UI by triggering ESB server's Web service.

Please help me in user creation and authentication and authorization using Identity server for above explain design. OR whether it is good approach to use the WSO2 product for web application.

Or any forum or mail address so that I can discuss the solution.

I Have post lots of question related to WSO2 But unanswered.

Please Help me WSO2 Community

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your needs may not require a separate installation of the WSO2 identity server.  The standard user management features of the ESB should be sufficient for your use case.  The Your HR user should be able to create users from the ESB GUI.  The user management features of WSO2 ESB are well documented here [1].

If you need SSO functionality, I recommend using the Identity Server.  Here is a guide to setting up SSO, if you need it [2].

-Colin

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Introduction+to+User+Management
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+SSO+for+WSO2+Servers

Comment: As I mentioned, I want to use HTML for user login/logout or any other activity. Every server will have its own users, My question is How to integrate all the servers and using HTML for UIs.